# Передать java object to c struct и обратно

Tags: java, c

Имею дело с named pipes.
Нужно передать msg  типа struct (предварительно переделав его в байты с обьекта?) с java в c. А также получить из c (c msg) в виде байтов и сконвертировать их в java объект.
Как-то так )
Каким образом это можно сделать ?

Comment: гуглите `java jni`

Comment: Имею дело с named pipes. - я же сказал :)

Comment: Вот и работайте с ними на си (нативно). А JNI будет нужен для перемещения данных между c и java.

Comment: Не... для одного лишь сообщения , посылаемого по сети, подключать jni - громоздко это , как по мне ...  Да и jni не сделает мне то что мне сделает java в моем конкретном случае...

Comment: Так Вы свой конкретный случай (так, на всякий случай) и не описали в вопросе.

Comment: Да, но он не имеет большого значения для этого вопроса...

Comment: Какой вопрос - такие и ответы. Кстати, а каким это образом у Вас связаны сеть (`для одного лишь сообщения , посылаемого по сети`) и named pipes (сугубо локальная штука)?

Comment: named pipes  - это абсолютно не локальная штука ...

Comment: Смотря какая ОС.

Comment: У меня Винда (там Named Pipe server)

Answer (score 1):

Лучше не изобретать велосипед и использовать [Protocol Buffers](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers) или [Thrift](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Thrift).

Comment: Спасибо, но если не изобретать - то тогда json да и все ? Просто не хочется лишних библиотек подключать, хочется простяцкий голый код , как все это сделать наиболее лучшим образом...

Comment: Я же вам привел ссылки, не нужен никакой JSON, описываете свои структуры, получаете сериализаторы и десериализаторы. Без "лишних библиотек" сериализовывать и десериализовывать придется руками, правда вряд ли код получится простяцким при сколь-нибудь сложных структурах.

Comment: посмотрим.. ...

Comment: @Andreyua, эти вещи как раз написаны для межъязыкового взаимодействия, и созданы людьми, собаку на этом съевших. В большинстве случаев лучше все-таки использовать проверенные временем вещи, чем городить свое частное решение.

Comment: А я вот "любитель" городить свои частные решения :) Это преступление ? Не люблю лишние библиотеки... Но посмотрим, посмотрим ...

Comment: Нет, не преступление, конечно. Если вам нужно слать одно сообщение в пару полей, расширения взаимодействия не предвидится, и не хочется использовать никаких сторонних решений, можете сделать это руками. Но лучше разобраться в хорошем инструменте, и использовать его во всех таких случаях, хороший задел на будущее. Будет надежно и единообразно. ИМХО.

Comment: Ага. Абсолютно в духа Java (ресурсоемко и при росте загрузки компа почти не шевелится).

Comment: @avp, действительно, у кучи проектов в продакшене под огромными нагрузками шевелится, а у вас нет ;)

Comment: Почему это у меня? Я на ней и не пишу (почти), я только решаю комплексные проблемы (обычно возникающие под большими нагрузками)  у наших заказчиков (и частенько корни этого кроятся в java ... (в т.ч. в продуктах (и middleware) от самых больших корпораций (это чтобы Вы не подумали, что речь идет о кооп. "Рога и Копыта")))

Comment: У вас претензии конкретно к этим решениям? И какое отношение имеет к ним именно Java? Как вы определили ее дух тут?